# The 2nd parameter to `mongoose.model()` should be a schema or a POJO

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I tried to launch my application. I don't even know which file causes this problem.
So say me which file i should show you.

Here is app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { AssigmentsModule } from './posts/assigments.module';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env',
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGO_URI),
    AuthModule,
    AssigmentsModule,
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And here is this repo look at dev branch.
https://github.com/MoneyIgos/biuro-makowskaj-api/tree/dev

Answer (score 0):

I saw the your code on github, Maybe You have already figured it Out, I had the same problem few minutes back, this is How I solved

```
User Schema Looks Like this
    export const UserSchema = new Schema({
      username: { type: String, required: true },
      password: { type: String, required: true },
    });

const User = model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

Assignment Schema Looks Like this

```
 export const AssigmentSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { type: String, required: false },
  createdAt: {
    type: String,
    default: () => new Date(),
  },
});

const Assigment = model<IAssigment>('Assigment', AssigmentSchema);
```

In UserModule.ts

```
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }])],
```

instead it should be

```
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: User}])],
```

In AssignmentModule.ts

```
MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Assigment', schema: AssigmentSchema }]),
```

It should be like this

```
MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Assigment', schema: Assignment}]),
```